# make exe from jar using izpack

Tags: java, executable-jar, izpack

Hi i make exe from my jar file using izpack but in exe when i install it it shows izpack logo in exe file in top left corner so please give me the proper use of izpack

Comment: You mean you want to change the icon in the generated .exe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your install.xml file and find `<resources>` tag. Here you will find the image path that is displaying on the top left. Change it to yours. :)